# shingle facet count not giving exact count

Tags: solr, lucene, facet

I have defined following field :

```
<field name="rawText" type="common_shingle" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" /> 

<fieldType name="common_shingle" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
              <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern=".*_.*" replacement=""/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I am trying to get the shingle counts of the documents with this field. Although I am getting shingles with the query below. It is not giving me exact count of the shingles. I have tested it one 2 similar documents. But the shingle count is 0.

http://localhost:8983/solr/recommendation/select?category=doctor&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=rawText&facet.limit=10000

is there anything wrong with my field type or query?

I am trying to get the common shingles with the highest counts with the category name doctor.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this

http://localhost:8983/solr/recommendation/select?q=*&category=doctor&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=rawText&facet.limit=10000

Comment: not working.. its showing all the results not even the shingles